# Keep getting "Project Target Framework not installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, geographic-lib

After generating visual studio 2010 solution using cmake from source, the GeographicLib solution shows the following error on VS2010. [image: Error message when trying to load the solution]. I tried downloading and installing .net fx 4.0 but the error keeps coming.

Comment: That is a pretty odd error, given that the VS2010 installer always ensures that .NET 4.0 is available and provides the targeting pack for it.  Did you clean up too much?  What actually goes wrong when you ignore this error and build the program?  Ensure that the C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0 directory is available and its content looks good.  If not then re-run the VS2010 installer to repair.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can't build the solution since the only option I've is to go to the website and download or unload the project. and yes the path you gave me above is in place with all it's contents. I tried it on windows 7(the same solution and it builds without any error or preconditions). I think the problem is with Windows 10 operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for it and if some one faces the same problem, here is the solution that works for me. The error is because am using visual studio 2010 professional and when I changed to visual studio 2010 ultimate, Geographic lib builds and installs without any error.